# Попадаю в hardfault_handler при чтение данных из флешь памяти

Tags: c

Есть у меня вот такая структура .h:

```
    typedef const struct {
    const char name[20];         // имя
    const char textExtension[4]; // расширение
    const uint32_t size;         // размер в байтах
    const uniondate date;        // дата
    const uiniontime time;       // время
    const uint32_t numberSector; // номер сектора
    const uint32_t crc;          // контрольная сумма
    const uint32_t reserve[5];   // резерв
} headerFileList[256];

extern headerFileList *HeaderFileList;
```

в .c определил:

```
headerFileList *HeaderFileList;
```

в main.c добавил следующий код:

```
char text[4];

   HeaderFileList = ADDR_FLASH_SECTOR_7_BANK1;

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    for(uint8_t j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        text[j] = HeaderFileList[i]->textExtension[j];
    }
    }
```

Когда 'i' до 100 то данные считываются. Когда 'i' равна 100 и более происходит переход в 'hardfault'. Как  такое может быть?

Comment: По коду ошибок нет. Вы уверены, что не выходите за допустимый диапазон flash-памяти? Размер вашей структуры равен `(20+4+4+4+4+4+4+4*5)*256=0x4000` байт.

Comment: размер flash памяти 128 Кбайт.

Comment: Но у вас ведь какую-то часть занимает основная программа. Дайте определение константы ADDR_FLASH_SECTOR_7_BANK1.

Comment: '#define ADDR_FLASH_SECTOR_7_BANK1     ((uint32_t)0x080E0000) /* Base @ of Sector 7, 128 Kbytes */' программа начинается с адреса '0x08000000' размер программы 64 кБайта. Мы не попадаем в данную область.

Comment: 0x08000000+128×1024=0x08020000. Меньше, чем 0x080E0000. Вы уже за пределами flash-памяти. Какой у вас контроллер?